# How can I debug a template with directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS debug. I wonder if anyone can show me an example about how to debug a template with directive like `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, etc. What I need to see is how those directive initialized and how those variable been given and render, kinda like step debug in template.

I can set breakpoint if I define the controller, but when it comes AngularJS native directives and template, I have no idea how to do that

Comment: You may be able to use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en) in Chrome as an extension. It will help inspect scope. As far as stepping through, I am not sure of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to have your local copy of Angular JS script ( dont use min version - use full version)

Then in chrome, you can use debugger function or just use normal breakpoint in that AngularJS script.

Example :

```
var ngRepeatDirective = ['$parse', '$animate', function($parse, $animate) {
var NG_REMOVED = '$$NG_REMOVED';
var ngRepeatMinErr = minErr('ngRepeat');

var updateScope = function(scope, index, valueIdentifier, value, keyIdentifier, key, arrayLength) {
debugger; // Set the debugger inside 
            // this function
....
```